# Remove DataGridView column sorting, but keep mouse hover effect

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` which I disabled column sorting for using this LINQ statement:

```
((DataGridView)sender).Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>().ToList().ForEach(f => f.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable);
```

So far everything is fine. However, whenever I hover over any of the column headers, the headers no longer look like they're being hovered over.

Is there a way to disable column sorting while also keeping the ability to see which column you're hovering over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MSDN documentation for [`DataGridViewColumnSortMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumnsortmode(v=vs.110).aspx#Members) Members defines:

- `NotSortable`

  > The column can only be sorted programmatically, but it is not intended for sorting, so the column header will not include space for a sorting glyph.
- `Programmatic`

  > The column can only be sorted programmatically, and the column header will include space for a sorting glyph.

Technically, this means both options *disable column sorting* for users. Besides intent, the only differences between the two are *visual cues*, I.E. the sorting glyph and the hover highlighting.

Therefore, if you want the sorting look without any sorting, set the following mode and simply *don't do any programmatic sorting*.

```
DataGridViewColumn.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic;
```

[image: Sortable column vs non-sortable column]